# Does Passbook support delta updates for a pass

Tags: passbook

When Passbook requests a new pass from the server is it possible to return a delta update instead of the full pass?  The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/PassKit/Reference/PassKit_WebService/WebService.html) for "Getting the Latest Version of a Pass" only mentions that the GET request should return a HTTP status 200 with a payload of the pass data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, when updating the pass you have to provide a full new signed .pkpass bundle as per the documentation.

One of the reasons for this is that Passbook facilitates sharing and needs a complete, signed .pkpass bundle to attach to an email or iMessage.  Sending the pass plus files of incremental updates would add complexity, and sending an unsigned bundle would break the integrity of Passbook's security, effectively allowing users to modify the content of the pass.